# parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to write a method that accepts a generic input and returns null if the input is default and an XElement otherwise.

Btw, I'm pretty green at generic methods, and apparently at google-fu.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public static class ConversionClass<T>
{
    public static XElement newXElementOrNull<T>(string name, T val)
    {
        if ((T.type == "String") && (val == String.Empty))
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (val == default(T))
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            return new XElement(name, val);
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, C# does not like this.

It balks on the method signature (newXElementOrNull) saying:

Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'AddXMLTest.Converter'

And it highlights the T in the angled brackets and the T in the parameter.

To make matters worse it doesn't like the val == default(T) part because it says Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're missing so much code from this example to figure out what's really wrong here.  For example `val == default(T)` isn't valid the way you have written the example.  Also, clearly you have an `outer type` that uses `T` in a type parameter as well, but you haven't provided that example code.

Comment: FYI the naming convention for all non-private methods is (edit: not camelCase) PascalCase

Comment: Also, if ((T.type == "String") && (val == String.Empty)) is not valid.  Please provide a short but complete example that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Supporting documentation for 2 of the answers (at the time of writing) can be found on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcad0zb.aspx)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - it's spelled __camelCase__ but that rule does not apply to methods. This is not Java.

Comment: Not sure how I got an up vote on this train wreck of a question :)

Comment: @HenkHolterman - you're right, but I meant PascalCase :)

Comment: @GeorgeMauer - we are in agreement now.

Answer (score 6):

Apparently this method is inside a class that already specifies `<T>`. That means that you can omit this type parameter, methods of a generic class are automatically generic too.

I would expect `T.type` to cause errors as well but it depends on the  type-constraints on the outer class. To get a full answer, post the outer definition (not all members) of that class.

> it doesn't like the `val == default(T)`

That is most likely a follow-up error of the first.

Comment: I'd +1 you if I could my friend - but I'm out of votes. I guess we both had the same thought here. It's nice when you're answer is confirmed by people like you!

Answer (score 3):

> Type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter from outer type 'AddXMLTest.Converter'

So the class outside of this method (not shown) must be using `<T>` as well. You won't be able to do that. Name it (on the method that is) something like `<K>`.

> To make matters worse it doesn't like the val == default(T) part because it says Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'T' and 'T'.

This should be resolved when you stop using `<T>` and change it so something like `default(K)`.

Further, I'm pretty sure that this `T.type` isn't going to compile. I'm pretty sure that evaluation should be something like:

```
if ((val is typeof(string) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
```

Comment: the `is` parameter is for instances not types `T is typeof(string)` would not work

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, sorry. Right you are, thanks a lot, it's fixed!

Comment: In that case we have the issue that if val is null T might be a string but this will not trigger since `null is String == false`. Pretty much the `is` operator is not quite the correct tool for this. You probably want to do a direct comparison on types like in my answer or check `type1.IsAssignableFrom(type2)`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer, very good point. So that would look like `T.IsAssignableFrom(typeof(string))` right?

Comment: Other way around - `typeof(String).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T))` it makes perfect sense when you read it aloud but for some reason everyone (myself included) always gets it backwards. That being said, String is a sealed class and not possible to inherit from so checking `IsAssignableFrom` is overkill.

Answer (score 1):

You can no sooner do `T.type` than you can do `String.type` or `MyClass.type`

What you're looking for is something like

```
typeof(T) == typeof(String)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two invalid things which are `T.type == "String" && val == String.Empty` and `val == default(T)`. 
What about:

```
public static XElement newXElementOrNull<T>( string name, T val ) {
   if ( typeof(T) == typeof(String) && val.ToString() == String.Empty ) {
      return null;
   }

   if ( EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals( val, default( T ) ) ) {
      return null;
   }
   else {
      return new XElement( name, val );
   }
}
```